# LAME decode gives up early on long MP3 files?

Tags: mp3, lame

I am using Lame.exe 3.99.5 64-bit for Windows to decode some podcasts.  One podcast has particularly long epsiodes such as [this one](http://www.dancarlin.com/product/hardcore-history-54-blueprint-armageddon-v/), at **4.5 hours**.

When I download and decode [its MP3](http://traffic.libsyn.com/dancarlinhh/dchha54_Blueprint_for_Armageddon_V.mp3), I get a WAV file of **3.4 hours**. Presumably, it gave up partway through, although I see no error.  The same kind of problem happens with any long MP3 from this podcast.

**Is this a shortcoming of LAME?  Am I doing something wrong?**  Here is the command line and output (I snipped the full path):

```
C:\...\Temp>"C:\Program Files\Lame\lame.exe" --decode "C:\...\Temp\Show 54 - Blueprint for Armageddon V.mp3"

input:  C:\...\Temp\Show 54 - Blueprint for Armageddon V.mp3
        (44.1 kHz, 2 channels, MPEG-1 Layer III)
output: C:\...\Temp\Show 54 - Blueprint for Armageddon V.wav
        (16 bit, Microsoft WAVE)
skipping initial 529 samples (encoder+decoder delay)
Frame#625408/626055 128 kbps  L  R

C:\...\Temp>
```

Comment: Maybe a simple bug? Last LAME version was released in 2011. Can you decode the file with another program, e.g. `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 output.wav`?

Comment: FFMPEG seems to work, but with lots of overread messages--is that normal?  Anyway, the output file is complete and sounds good.

Comment: Hm. I don't know where these messages come from. There is at least one open bug report, but it's about 24 kHz WAV/MP3 decoding only. Since ffmpeg worked, I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the last version of LAME was released in 2011, I guess that you're experiencing a bug that only occurs with long material—maybe some memory allocation issue.

Unless something in the file itself is broken, I'd [download ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) and use that to do the job:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 output.wav
```